# How do you disable rel='noreferrer' for external links?

Tags: configuration, links, seo

Our `ProtectExternalLinksWithBlankTarget` is set to true so all our external links have the `rel='noopener noreferrer'` attribute, but we need to be able to allow some external links to be recognized as actual referrals from our site. Are there any controls in Sitecore that allow users to disable one or both the *noopener* or/and *noreferrer* values in the rel attribute?

Comment: Remove the `target="_blank"` on those links

Comment: We do want our external links to open in new tabs while passing referrer data.